# GORM creates duplicates on many2many

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gorm

I am using GORM in my Go Gin API and want to create an association between my User and the Role table. So far, I have simply followed the documentation, but I am running into a problem.
Here are my used models:

```
type User struct {
gorm.Model
FirstName string
LastName string
Email string `gorm:"unique"`
Password []byte
Roles []Role `gorm:"many2many:user_roles"`
}

type Role struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}
```

While I'm still developing, I want to write data directly to the database when I start the API. For this I create the following:

```
Db.Create(&User{
FirstName:"Jon",
LastName:"Doe",
Email: "jon@doe.local",
Password: encoded,
Roles:       []Role{
    {Name: "admin"},
    {Name: "service"},
},
})
Db.Create(&User{
FirstName:"Jon",
LastName:"Doe",
Email: "jon2@doe.local",
Password: encoded,
Roles:       []Role{
    {Name: "admin"},
    {Name: "service"},
},})
```

This way I want each name to appear only once in the role table. The corresponding ID should be used in the automatically created user_roles table each time such an entry is created.
What happens, however, is this:
**Roles Table:**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | admin |
| 2 | service |
| 3 | admin |
| 4 | service |

**User_Role Table:**

| user_id | role_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

I have read through https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html and tried Omit but nothing worked yet.
I hope someone has an idea or already solved the same problem. Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**
When trying "try sending just the role IDs instead of role names" i do it like this:

```
        Db.Create(&User{
        FirstName:"Jon",
        LastName:"Doe",
        Email: "jon2@doe.local",
        Password: encoded,
        Roles:       []Role{
            {ID: 1},
            {ID: 2},
        },})
```

This gives me the error

> cannot use promoted field Model.ID in struct literal of type Role

**2. Edit**
The ID needs to be listed seperated in the Role model, it does not work just with the gorm.Model

```
type Role struct {
gorm.Model
ID uint `gorm:"primarykey"`
Name string
}
```

Comment: Without using Role ID in the second `Create` call, you are basically creating new roles, even if they have the same names as the existing ones (the operation will create new roles unless you have a unique constraint on role name). When using already created roles in a `Create` call, try sending just the role IDs instead of role names.

Comment: I have tried as edited but get the error "cannot use promoted field Model.ID in struct literal of type Role"